# Angular sharing data

Tags: angular, data-sharing

I have 2 component parent and child relationship.

I want to call parent component method in my child component.

I tried @Input decorator but that was not working.

Please help

Comment: Add the code of those two components

Comment: And include information about the project, the final goal you're looking for.

Comment: Please include some code.

Answer (score 1):

**Parent listens for child event**

The child component exposes an EventEmitter property with which it emits events when something happens. The parent binds to that event property and reacts to those events.

The child's EventEmitter property is an output property, typically adorned with an @Output decoration as seen in this VoterComponent:

`component-interaction/src/app/voter.component.ts`

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-voter',
  template: `
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <button (click)="vote(true)"  [disabled]="didVote">Agree</button>
    <button (click)="vote(false)" [disabled]="didVote">Disagree</button>
  `
})
export class VoterComponent {
  @Input()  name: string;
  @Output() voted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  didVote = false;

  vote(agreed: boolean) {
    this.voted.emit(agreed);
    this.didVote = true;
  }
}
```

Clicking a button triggers emission of a true or false, the boolean payload.

The parent VoteTakerComponent binds an event handler called onVoted() that responds to the child event payload $event and updates a counter.

`component-interaction/src/app/votetaker.component.ts`

```
import { Component }      from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vote-taker',
  template: `
    <h2>Should mankind colonize the Universe?</h2>
    <h3>Agree: {{agreed}}, Disagree: {{disagreed}}</h3>
    <app-voter *ngFor="let voter of voters"
      [name]="voter"
      (voted)="onVoted($event)">
    </app-voter>
  `
})
export class VoteTakerComponent {
  agreed = 0;
  disagreed = 0;
  voters = ['Narco', 'Celeritas', 'Bombasto'];

  onVoted(agreed: boolean) {
    agreed ? this.agreed++ : this.disagreed++;
  }
}
```

The framework passes the event argument—represented by $event—to the handler method, and the method processes it.

#### You should read the full guide at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

@Input decorator is used for child component to get data from parent component. To call method from parent component from child component you have a two option:

1. Use @Output decorator with event emitter to emit event from child component to parent and on that event you can call method in parent component.

   `@Output() output: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();`
2. Second option is to use service